# Cancelling an operation on parallel collections if it takes too long - Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, scala-collections

Is it possible to cancel an operation on a parallel scala collection? E.g if I do `myList.par.map(...)`, is it possible to cancel that later on, and just get the elements which have already been processed?

Comment: I don't think this is possible and I wonder if someone sees an easy way to implement something like this.

Comment: Did you try to use a Streaming mechanism to do this?

Comment: @sparkr No, would love to see what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no built in answer I found - I decided to just set a time limit and have the iterations stop running if the time elapsed crossed the threshold.

```
val MAX_TIME: Long = 120.minutes.toMillis
val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
val isTimeRemaining = () => (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) <= MAX_TIME

val processor:Seq[R] = (i:T) => {
  if (isTimeRemaining())
     //do some processing here
  else
    Nil
}

val results:Seq[T] = Random.shuffle(instances)
                      .par
                     .flatMap(processor)
                     .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
                     .toList
```

Answer (score 3):

Cancelling an operation on a List might not be possible as there is no API from the Scala library to do this. But you have some options to get this done. For example., if your List is a stream and if that stream is wrapped in a Future like this:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val stream = scala.concurrent.Future { 1 #:: 2 #:: 3 #:: Stream.empty }
stream: scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int]] = Success(Stream(1, ?))
```

You could cancel the Future at any time you want - based on some timeout!

Another option is to use Observables and an Observer (the reactive ones) where you could model your List as an Observable and subscribe with an Observer to this Observable. You could then cancel the subscriber at any point in time you want! Have a look at the Monix library if this is of interest to you!

Comment: It is an interesting idea but I don't get how to make it work with `.par` (i.e. some kind of parallel computation) which seems to be the whole point.

Comment: You could Futurize your List and then parallelize it!

Comment: sparkr, I don't think I get this idea. Could you elaborate in a bit more details how you can "Futurize" the list to support cancellation of parallel map?

Comment: Something like this: Future(List(1,2)).map(elem => elem.par.map(_ + 2))

Comment: I still don't get how this helps with cancellation assuming that I (or rather OP) want to get those results that have already been processed before cancellation. AFAIU with this approach you can only throw away the whole process. And it still will consume CPU until processing is finished so this doesn't look as a cancellation to me. Did I miss some clever trick in your plan?

Comment: Hmmm... I did not think about the results part of the already processed elements in the List. You could perhaps wrap this whole thing around a recursive function (using the accumulator pattern) and at the moment you cancel the Future, just return the accumulator which would contain the results that have been computed so far! Does this seem reasonable?